# Let A, B, C be sets. Prove that (A − C) − (B − C) ⊆ A − B.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I've been trying to learn this on my own and I'm pretty new. Could someone walk me through the steps for solving this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you have to prove an inclusion of sets, say $X \subseteq Y$, you have to prove that for any $x \in X$ we have $x \in Y$. So let us do that here.

**Step 1.** Let $x \in (A - C) - (B - C)$, we need to show that $x \in A - B$.

Now it is useful to see what this means. So we write out the definitions of the sets we are dealing with.

**Step 2.** So we have $x \in A - C$ and $x \not \in B - C$, and we have to show that $x \in A$ and $x \not \in B$.

Maybe at this point you can already see how to finish the argument. If not, then let's write out the definitions one more step.

**Step 3.** From $x \in A - C$ we know that $x \in A$ and $x \not \in C$. From $x \not \in B - C$ we know that $x \not \in B$ and $x \in C$ (this one is a bit trickier, if you can't see this directly, drawing a Venn diagram might help).

Always keep in mind what the goal was we were trying to prove, because often people keep on writing proofs while they are already there! In this case what we needed to prove is already there in step 3, just spread out over multiple statements. So let's piece everything together.

**Step 4.** We had to show $x \in A$ and $x \not \in B$ (see step 2). From the first sentence in step 3 we have $x \in A$, and the second sentence in step 3 tells us that $x \not \in B$, as required.

So if you write down these steps you have a complete and detailed proof!

Comment: thank you kind sir!!